# In Windows 10, how can I enlarge thumbnail size?

Tags: windows-10, icons, thumbnails

Even after selecting `Extra large icons`, the thumbnails are too small for me to discern the images. I completed the steps for:

1. [Option 1](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/18834-thumbnail-previews-file-explorer-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html#option1): 'To Turn On Thumbnail Previews in File Explorer'.
2. Changing Image Thumbnail Size per this [Registry Hack Method](http://www.technipages.com/windows-change-image-thumbnail-size).

But my thumbnails have not enlarged.

Comment: Hold the “CTRL” key and scroll the wheel on your mouse to enlarge or decrease the size of the icons.

Comment: @vembutech, is that icon by icon, or the action affects all icons?  Does the icon need to be selected?  How long does the result persist?  Thanks.

Comment: @vembutech That option does not appear to resolve the problem, because it produces only the default sizes, the biggest of which is `Extra large icons` that are still too small for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got a new laptop with 
(*Windows 10 and 4K Resolution*.)
Changing the thumbnail size to `Extra Large` increases the **spacing**, but doesn't make them any larger & the `Registry Hack` didn't seem do do anything!

-
**The only way I found to make them larger, was to change my screen's Resolution to a lower setting.**
Although it makes everything else larger as well, which could be annoying to some people.

Answer (score -1):

The way I do it is to hold `ctrl` and scroll the mouse wheel up while in the folder.

Another way to do this is to go to:

Windows Explorer -> View tab -> Large/Extra Large Icons (Under Layout section).

This transforms my view from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTqng.jpg) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGgW2.jpg).

Comment: this does not make much difference on my 2560x1440 screen.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make the thumbnail size between large and extra large and this did the trick.